# ListView data parse and navigation

Tags: android, database, listview, items

I have list of items. This items have details associated with them, in the database. I want to click on a item of the list and that navigate to a activity that shows the details of this items in a EditText. I already have the navigation part but i can't do the most important part that consist in show the details of the item i clicked.

this is my method for navigation

```
edition.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String aux= (String) lt.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(infoList.this, EditarLocais.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Can somebody help?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it in "Android Way"

use ContentProvider

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent itemIntent = new Intent(this, ItemActivity.class);
    listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath("content://my.app.content/edition", Long.toString(id)));
    startActivity(listIntent);
}
```

then in ItemActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item_activity);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, new String[] { "All", "Columns", "That" }, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Option #1:

The [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class could be what you're looking for. There is a very good answer that explains how to use it and actually it is everything you need. You can find the answer here: [Android: How to declare global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables?tab=votes#tab-top).

Option #2:

Use `Intent.putExtra(...)` method to send further data from your previous `Activity` to your next `Activity`.

Option #3:

This is a dirty quick fix (not recommended). Declare your data object as `static` and reach it by using `YourActivity.mMyDataObject`.